# How to match regexp starting from specific character index in Ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.8

In Ruby 1.9 I would use `String#match(regexp,start_index)`. I'm sure there must be a (computationally efficient) equivalent in Ruby 1.8, but I can't find it. Do you know what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is ***no efficient way*** to match a Regexp against a large string, starting from an arbitrary index, in pure Ruby 1.8.

This seems like a major flaw. I guess the moral of the story is: use Ruby 1.9!

Answer (score 3):

You could start the regexp with `^.{start_index}`

or take the substring first before performing the match.

Alternatively, if you're constrained to using Ruby 1.8, but can install your own libraries then you could use [Oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Sure... but notice I asked for a "computationally efficient" alternative.

Comment: @AlexD: What makes you think `^.{n}` isn't computationally efficient? The regex engine probably just offsets into the string and starts working from there. A quick bit of benchmarking suggests that `^.{n}` is slightly faster than the obvious alternative (`s[i..-1].match(re)`).

Comment: I tried it in `irb` before answering, and it's inefficient. O(n) in the length of the string, and I will be using this to parse large files which may be tens or hundreds of megabytes. Based on the tests I have done, it could take as much as 30 seconds for a single match in such a case.

Comment: @mikej, installing Oniguruma is an interesting idea (I didn't know it was possible), but unfortunately this is for a (somewhat popular) gem, and it's simply not acceptable to tell all Ruby 1.8 users that "you have to install Oniguruma to use this gem".